# Check empty float or integer value in golang

Tags: go, integer, floating

I'm trying to check if my integer or float value is empty. But type error is thrown.

Tried:

```
if foo == nil    
//Error: cannot convert nil to type float32
//all other methods I Tried also throw type errors too
```

Comment: What do you mean integer or float value? You can't have it be both.

Comment: an integer or float cannot be nil.  Default value is 0

Comment: that why I specified or in between

Comment: hmm. thats a issue for me now. I should ask this question in qor github issue.

Comment: thanks for your time guys

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The [zero values](https://tour.golang.org/basics/12) for integer and floats is 0. `nil` is not a valid integer or float value.

A pointer to an integer or a float can be `nil`, but not its value.

This means you either check for the zero value:

```
if foo == 0 {
  // it's a zero value
}
```

Or you deal with pointers:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var intPointer *int

    // To set the value use:
    // intValue := 3
    // intPointer = &intValue

    if intPointer == nil {
        fmt.Println("The variable is nil")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("The variable is set to %v\n", *intPointer)
    }
}
```

Comment: For the pointer example, alternatively you can set the value the pointer points to using the dereference operator `*`: https://play.golang.org/p/9TrwjUkr4I

Comment: Thank you @Simone Carletti , is there a GoLang manual reference  "The zero values for integer and floats is 0. nil is not a valid integer or float value" ?